# Scheduled autobackup in Oracle 11G

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm currently working in oracle 11G, in my project I got a task to schedule an auto backup of all the Database in respective server. I asked the same query to some of my friend and others , they suggested me to use DBMS_scheduler and some jobs also. But I didn't get that.
So will you please help me to resolve this kind of situation with an accurate and systematic answer. I'll be very thankful to you.
Thanks and regards.

Comment: What is your question? Is your question about programming? We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed. Provide details. Share your research.

Answer (score 0):

Below is simple example calling external script using DBMS_SCHEDULER

```
BEGIN
        DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
                job_name => '"SYS"."MAKE_BACKUP"',
                job_type => 'EXECUTABLE',
                job_action => 'C:\this\is\backup\script.bat',
                start_date => sysdate,
                repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY',
                enabled => true);
    END;
```

Script format will vary depending on your OS, e.g. *.bat on Windows or *.sh on Linux. In that script you should call backuping command, RMAN or EXPDP. Check Oracle docs for correct syntax:
http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/RCMRF/toc.htm

Simplest Windows based script:

```
set ORACLE_SID=SUKOY2
@(
   echo backup database;
) > %temp%\make_rman_backup.dat

rman target user/password @%temp%\make_rman_backup.dat
```

Comment: Hi, your scheduler is working fine but the problem is with the script, as I'm using RMAN for taking the backup. Using that script and scheduler, I'm able to login in RMAN but the rest of command as "backup database" is not executing. What should I do?

Comment: How your script looks like?

Comment: Export ORACLE_SID=SUKOY2,   RMAN catalog RMAN_DBA/password,  connect target sys/password@197.5....../prod,  backup database

Comment: I have used your linux script but the problem is using this script I'm only to connect to rman, backup database command is not executing. I've tried it with run also. But the same thing happens again n again

Answer (score 0):

What you show as your script is not a working script.
What is your OS?

If Windows, here's a basic, no-frils, just-to-get-you-started:

```
set ORACLE_SID=<name of your database>
set ORACLE_HOME=<as appropriate>
echo backup database > rmancmd.txt
rman target / @rmancmd.txt
```

If linux, I prefer

```
export ORACLE_SID=<name of database>
export ORAENV_ASK=NO
. oraenv
#the above sets the environment
rman target / <<EOF
backup database;
EOF
```

Comment: I have used your linux script but the problem is using this script I'm only to connect to rman, backup database command is not executing. I've tried it with run also. But the same thing happens again n again

Comment: I don't see your script.  I don't see how you execute your script. I don't see the output of your script.  I don't see any error messages.